# /dev/tty.usbmodem disappears after Mountain Lion upgrade

Tags: macos, usb

I just upgraded from 10.6 to Mountain Lion.  Prior to the upgrade I was using an Arduino and talking to it via `/dev/tty.usbmodemmfa141`. That device does not appear to exist anymore.

When I plug in the Arduino via USB, the Mac should detect it and add `/dev/tty.usbmodemXXXX` for communication, but it does not. How can I force the Mac to see the Arduino or search for USB devices?

Comment: I am seeing the same problem with my Keyspan USB to DB9 adapter after upgrading to 10.10.4

Answer (score 1):

I beleive that plugging the arduino into the Mac via USB causes the port to be created automatically as part of the device detection.

If it's not showing up, then the OS is not detecting it as a device or the name of the device is no longer waht you expect it to be.

It may well be that under Mountain Lion, that the port name has changed, I found a [script over on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11642615) that detects for changes in the /dev folder by comparing a list of all the devices in /dev before and after the device is plugged in.

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP but on a new Mac running Mountain Lion (not upgraded). When I plug in the Arduino it powers on but does not add the tty.usbmodemXXXX device in /dev